# PhoneGap + jQueryMobile - Populating database

Tags: sql, database, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working with phonegap & jquery mobile for a mobile native application.

I have on html file multiple jquery mobile pages in it.
In my html file I have :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
// VARIABLES
var db;
// INIT FUNCTION 
function onBodyLoad(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
// ONDEVICE READY FUNCTION
function onDeviceReady(){
    db = window.openDatabase("shopit", "1.0", "SHOPIT DB", 1000000); // RETURN NEW DB OBJECT
    db.transaction(populateDB, onTxError, onTxSuccess); // POPULATE DB WITH SUPERMARKTES + SHOPS + CATEGORIES + PRODUCTS
}

// POPULATE DB
function populateDB(tx) {

   // SUPERMARKETS
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SUPERMARKETS');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc) VALUES (1, "Aldi", "images/supermarkets/aldi.jpg")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc) VALUES (2, "Carrefour", "images/supermarkets/carrefour.jpg")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc) VALUES (3, "Colruyt", "images/supermarkets/colruyt.jpg")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc) VALUES (4, "Delhaize", "images/supermarkets/delhaize.jpg")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc) VALUES (5, "Intermarche", "images/supermarkets/intermarche.jpg")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc) VALUES (6, "Lidl", "images/supermarkets/lidl.jpg")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc) VALUES (7, "Ocool", "images/supermarkets/ocool.jpg")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc) VALUES (8, "Okay", "images/supermarkets/okay.jpg")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc) VALUES (9, "Smatch", "images/supermarkets/smatch.jpg")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SUPERMARKETS (id, name, imgsrc) VALUES (10, "Spar", "images/supermarkets/spar.jpg")');

}
</script>
```

Now my question is: "Will the function 'populateDB' be called everytime a page loads? And how can I change this it only loads one time?"

My pages are structured like this in one html file:

```
<div data-role="page" id="list">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-iconpos="bottom">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="currlist" href="#" data-icon="custom" >My list</a></li>
                <li><a id="currlist" href="#" data-icon="custom" >Producten</a></li>
                <li><a id="currlist" href="#" data-icon="custom" >Favorieten</a></li>
                <li><a id="currlist" href="#" data-icon="custom" >Promoties</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
         <ul data-role="listview" id="list"></ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>SHOP-it Applicatie</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="newlist">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Nieuwe lijst</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#newlist" onclick="showSupermarkets();" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Supermarkten</a>
                <a href="#newlistshops" onclick="showShops();" data-role="button">Winkels</a>
        </div>  
        <div id="supermarkets">
        </div>
        <a href="#newlist_other" data-role="button">Andere lijst aanmaken</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>SHOP-it</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it on PageCreate Event for first Page .

```
$("#list").on('pagecreate', function() {
     onBodyLoad();
});
```